# Rename folder on remote server

Tags: batch, batch-file, shell-script, remote-access, batch-rename

I am calling a .bat file which contains the following command

**net use \\128.545.k.k\E_Drive /user:Username psw**  to connect to a remote server.

I would like to rename a folder on the remote server i am connected to

ren \\128.545.k.k\E:\abc  **rename abc folder to xyz**.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Show o r type t h e words o f t h e error message indicating y o u cannot do this on the remote server in your answer by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mapped \\128.545.k.k\**E_Drive** then use that in your `ren` command (not **E:**):

`ren \\128.545.k.k\E_Drive\abc xyz`

Comment: When i use ren \\128.545.k.k\E_Drive\abc xyz in .bat file and execute it says path not found.

Comment: Can you run commands in a prompt first? Does `net use` confirm the path exists? Use a `if exist \\128.545.k.k\E_Drive\abc` to test the folder is there before you try renaming it

Comment: Yeah the net use confirms the path does exist but i guess we cant rename using ren command on remote server